# PHP CronJob doesn't work

Tags: php, unix, cron, apache2, debian

I'm trying to set up a cronjob which sends me an email when it runs.

when I execute the file using a ssh command via PuTTY, it works, it also works when I set it up as an URL, but doesn't work when setting using absolute path.

Here is what all I've tried till now :
Does work :

```
    *   *   *   *   *   http://example.com/cron/cron.php
```

Doesn't work :

```
    *   *   *   *   *   php /var/www/clients/client2/web6/web/global/cron/cron.php

    *   *   *   *   *   /var/www/clients/client2/web6/web/global/cron/cron.php

    *   *   *   *   *   /usr/bin/php /var/www/clients/client2/web6/web/global/cron/cron.php
```

All 3 that I listed in 'doesn't work' works when executed as commands through PuTTY

File permissions are all sorted out and are 777 for the cron file, and the directory it resides in.

I'm using IspConfig3 and Debian and Apache2, if that matters

EDIT : here's the code in cron.php :

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Cronjob <cronjob@example.com>' . "\r\n";
mail("peeyush@example.com", "Cronjob Complete - ". date('d-m-Y'), "At".date("H:i:s"), $headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this to find the directory:

```
 <?php print __FILE__; ?>
```

Try this:

```
*   *   *   *   * php /var/www/clients/client2/web6/web/global/cron/cron.php
```

This is how my crons work on my website.

Comment: didnt work either, nor do I see why it would work since clients isn't the root dir

Comment: What is the root directory?

Comment: Hmm, what is your username?

Comment: I login from root account but I'm adding cronjobs via IspConfig control panel

Comment: Run the line I put in my answer and tell me what you get

Comment: /var/www/clients/client2/web6/web/global/cron/new.php , whit new.php being the name of the file I put that code in

Comment: Turns out it was  a permission issue, It wasn't working when setting up through admin account but worked when cron was set up through client

Answer (score 1):

You probably have some relative includes in your PHP file.
So:

- Change the paths in your PHP file to absolute paths,
- or first move to the dir in your cronjob and then execute the PHP file. You can do this by executing the cronjob like this: cd /var/www/clients/client2/web6/web/global/cron/; php cron.php

Hope this helps.

Comment: nope, the cron file isnt using any includes atm. its simply trying to mail me.

Comment: Then it seems you added the cronjob to a user without rights to execute the script.

Comment: all the files related with cronjob have the permission 0777

Comment: How does that work? I'm setting up cronjobs using IspConfig Control panel, and its executing the cron job that is specified using a link, but not one with absolute path

Answer (score 1):

- - - - - [USER] /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/clients/client2/web6/web/global/cron/cron.php

User must have rights to execute your script.
Also, if it not helps, check logs: tail -f /var/log/cron

Comment: do i type in [USER] as it is or do I replace it with something?

Comment: place a username who have rights to exectute your scripts.
it could be the same user as you use for SSH.

* * * * * username /usr/local/bin/php script.php

Comment: root /usr/bin/php /var/www/clients/client2/web6/web/global/cron/cron.php  << is this how its supposed to look like?